# Is there a word or phrase to define several words linked by hyphens, such as in "a sit-back-and-wait-for-it attitude"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives, terminology, compound-adjectives

some more examples:

- "And she gave me that **aren't-I-just-gorgeous** smile."
- "The **I-did-it-my-way** approach."
- "A **from-this-day-forward-I-have-no-son** scene."

Comment: I answered this a while back. When using a sentence, it is more than a compound adjective. I guess I should say close as this is a duplicate, of sorts. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574633/constructions-of-the-form-he-has-committed-i-dont-know-how-many-crimes/574650#574650 So, I call these hyperextensions .

Comment: Also, don't confuse the use of compound modifiers and sentences as modifiers. They are not the same at all. Yours are all sentences used as modifiers.

Comment: I would say "hypernated".

Comment: I tried my damndest best to answer this a long time ago but go shot down. I stand by my answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574633/constructions-of-the-form-he-has-committed-i-dont-know-how-many-crimes/574650#574650 All I could come up with was: hyperextension of adjectives, which, by the way, can be a full sentence.

Comment: @Lambie   I really don't understand what you're complaining about.  The original question was posted eight years ago, on Aug 8th, and answered on the same day,  You've answered a similar question in 2021, six years later.  What's wrong?

Comment: I am just saying that when I tried to answer it after you asked it, people took a long time to respond positively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more than a hyphenated compound modifier (*a to-do list*). It's a stacked hyphenated compound modifier.

[Bonnie Mills, at Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/stacked-modifiers) has a relevant article, starting:

> Today’s episode concerns a what-you-may-have-been-wondering-about
>   topic. That sure was a mouthful, and it illustrates the problem of
>   stacked modifiers, which occurs when you string together too many
>   words to describe a noun at the end of the mouthful.

Though the examples given here are quirky, punchy and easy to understand, and fine in informal registers, caution has to be exercised to avoid confusion or silliness.

And I'd say that trying to analyse these nonce coinings as other than compound adjectives is a futile exercise (though their origins are transparent).

Comment: It actually isn't. The OP's examples are full-on sentences.

Comment: OP asks 'Is there a word or phrase to define several words linked by hyphens?' and takes care to bolden the hyphenated strings they're asking about in the sentences given.

Comment: But the OP is mistaken. Those are not normal compound adjectives. **Those are entire sentences used as adjectives**. The OP is a Brazilian Portuguese speaker, fyi. But others (see my linked answer) also mistakenly say compound adjectives.

Comment: An unremarkable subset of the whole set. For instance,  'what-you-may-have-been-wondering-about' is a non-sententially-derived multi-hyphenated compound (it doesn't matter what the elements are; look at the different POSs of elements of compound nouns and compound verbs).

Comment: Her feelings, if any, were not shown. [sentence] //From this day forward I have no son [sentence]//I did it my way [sentence]. No derivation and three full sentences. //For some reason, people here are stuck on the term hyphenated compound modifier. I'd say: hyphenated sentence modifier, myself.

Answer (score 3):

It is a hyphenated compound modifier!

> How to stop worrying about compound modifiers Monday, 1 Feb 2010, by Linda Lowenthal -
>
> http://www.copyediting.com/how-stop-worrying-about-compound-modifiers

Comment: Shouldn't that be hyphenated-compound-modifier? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Going with Lambie's suggestion that the asker intended to find a name for 'whole sentences' used as a modifier in a noun phrase, this phenomenon should be pretty straight forward to categorize.

First, any clause that is not itself a main clause is subordinate, and since these clauses are functioning as a dependent in a noun phrase, they would have to be classed as ***subordinate clauses***.

Second, since these clauses are headed by finite verbs (tensed verbs that is), we can say that they are ***finite subordinate clauses***.

Third, since they have no perceivable difference from ordinary finite clauses that could stand on their own as a sentence, we might say they are ***unmarked finite subordinate clauses***. However, we could also conclude that they are in fact marked as subordinate by their hyphenation, though this seems to fall into the category of punctuation more than syntax, and would not apply were we to hear them spoken. Also, in many instances, they are in fact not marked by hyphenation.

> I'm a member of the **why bother** generation myself.

That said, I'd think the string of words making up the clause would be uttered at a quicker pace, and with less of a pause between words, especially when they get longer. Or, alternatively, there would be a pause after uttering the determiner and another after the clause.

But, on the overall, it would probably still be best to refer to them as unmarked as they would be indistinguishable from main clauses out of context.

Now, it remains to determine what exactly their function is in noun phrase structure. Since they appear in the pre-head position, and are not acting as determiner, they must be either a pre-head modifier or complement. We could posit that they are modifiers (allowed by almost any head noun) or complements (allowed by only a certain limited subset of head nouns).

The modifier categorization seems warranted here as the head noun is seen as characterized by the content of the clause (but maybe not literally communicating it), or specifically designated for the person or personified thing that would utter it. This allows them to be used with almost any head noun.

> I was sitting all alone at [the I-did-it-my-way table].
>
> [His I-did-it-my-way smile] really irked me.
>
> They were surprised by [my I-did-it-my-way declaration].

In the third example, I may not have literally said the words 'I did it my way', but something that could be summed up that way.

This contrasts with finite subordinate clauses acting as post-head dependent in NPs, which are only allowed by certain head nouns and hence are complements.

> They were surprised by [my **declaration** (that) I did it my way].
>
> *They were surprised by [my **smile** (that) I did it my way].

In conclusion, the most accurate way to refer to these constructions would be ***unmarked finite subordinate clauses acting as pre-head modifiers in NPs***. If we wanted to specify that they were hyphenated, then I suppose that could be added: ***hyphenated unmarked finite subordinate clauses acting as pre-head modifiers in NPs***. If we then decided that in fact the hyphenation did in fact mark them as subordinate, I suppose we'd have to call them ***hyphenated syntactically-unmarked finite subordinate clauses acting as pre-head modifiers in NPs***.

If we adopt the term *content clause* for a finite subordinate clause, the name could be shortened slightly to ***unmarked content clauses acting as pre-head modifiers in NPs.***

---

But, why aren't they compound adjectives?

It would seem unwise to categorize these as adjectives as they cannot be used predicatively, do not readily take the typical range of dependents that adjectives would, and are not gradable (though we could have more or less of an I-told-you-so attitude).

> *He **seemed** I-told-you-so.
>
> ?His **very** I-told-you-so attitude bothered me.
>
> ?His **more** I-told-you-so attitude bothered me.

Compare with a compound adjective like *easy-going*:

> He seemed easy-going.
>
> His very easy-going attitude bothered me.
>
> His more easy-going attitude bothered me.

Furthermore, as Lambie has pointed out, their distribution does not match that of adjectives. They can, in unhyphenated form, appear in functions that adjectives cannot.

> *I did it my way*. [main clause]
>
> I **thought** *I did it my way*. [complement of reporting verb]
>
> He was **afraid** *I did it my way*. [complement of adjective]
>
> He was angry **after** *I did it my way* [complement of preposition]

So, since the range of dependents they may take and their distribution (outside of pre-head modifier in an NP) does not resemble that of adjectives, they should not be classed as such.

Comment: But 'nuclear' and 'boiling' likewise fail the familiar tests you invoke. As do the accepted members of the compound adjective subclass  'labour-saving' and 'third-floor'. Distribution is surely the more sensible test.

Comment: I have to say **I laud your effort**. It's been so frustrating having to repeat over and over that this thing is not about a compound adjective.  That said, I'm not sure I agree with the idea of a subordinate clause. For me, now that I think about this **again**, is that they are full-on SVP's functioning as premodifiers.

Comment: The most sensible test is: Is it a stand-alone sentence?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, the old anything-that-functions-as-a-prehead-modifier-in-a-noun-phrase-is-an-adjective argument. I don't buy that. Also, I'm not sure what standard we're using to judge 'accepted members of the compound adjective subclass'; 'third-floor' seems a clear nominal in _a third-floor apartment_, notwithstanding the fact that it is hyphenated and functioning as a pre-head modifier. Distribution in fact points to these not being adjectives, seeing as adjectives cannot be used as standalone sentences - a defining characteristic of the element under consideration.

Comment: @Lambie But they are not stand-alone sentences: they are embedded in a larger construction - a noun phrase, making them by definition **subordinate** clauses. I agree with the test _Can they be used as stand-alone sentences?_, but that simply proves that they are **unmarked** subordinate clauses when they appear as modifier in an NP.

Comment: The fact they can stand alone is what distinguishes them from a compound hyphenated adjective. Not the fact of subordination.

Comment: @Lambie Agreed. I've added the fact that their distribution differs from that of adjectives to my answer.