# What part of speech do the quoted constructions belong to?

Tags: parts-of-speech, compound-adjectives

This yoghurt is ...

- "getting out of these shoes" good
- "not catching the bouquet" good,
- "not getting stuck with a groom's man shorter than you" good.

I have found no articles on this sort of (it seems to me) intensifiers/constructions. Any clues?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a word or phrase to define several words linked by hyphens, such as in "a sit-back-and-wait-for-it attitude"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265549/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-to-define-several-words-linked-by-hyphens-such-as-in) Some more examples: "And she gave me that aren't-I-just-gorgeous smile." / "The I-did-it-my-way approach." / "A from-this-day-forward-I-have-no-son scene." (the nonce **stacked premodifiers** are normally hyphenated.) Here, before 'good', as you say they are intensifiers.

Comment: ... Here, they might be seen as snowclones of 'finger-lickin' good'.

Comment: Any phrase or clause that is identifiable may be frozen and used as a descriptive pre-nominal adjective modifier. Usually the frozen chunk is identifiable as an experience that produces an emotional effect (especially if it's intended to describe a _good_ feeling, as here). This is very informal talk.