# Constructions of the form 'He has committed I don't know how many crimes.'

Tags: grammar, clauses

What is the grammar (or syntax, if you will) of constructions of the form of the below sentence?

> He has committed I don't know how many crimes.

In this sentence, for example, what is the grammatical role of the clause 'I don't know how many crimes'. Is it the object of the verb 'committed'? What type of clause is it?

Comment: The implication is that he has committed _many_ crimes - so many that the speaker cannot guess the number of them.

Comment: Actually, it should be punctuated like this; He has committed I-don't-know-how-many crimes. This larger-than-life character was truly amazing. Ergo, those phrases function as adjectives.

Comment: It helps me to break down the sentence by bracketing a phrase that can be swapped. 
I see this as 
He has committed (I don't know how many) crimes.
I think of this as an adjective phrase like 'numerous' or 'a few', where the bracketed phrase replaces an adjective associated with number.

However the feel of the sentence for me implies numerous. As in I've lost count.

Comment: Related ELL question: [How to analyze this sentence - "I have to wait for I don't know how long."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56339/how-to-analyze-this-sentence-i-have-to-wait-for-i-dont-know-how-long)

Comment: Perhaps seeing 'I don't know how many' here as a compound quantifier like 'a lot of' makes sense. Yes, there is semantic content not completely bleached away, but 'galore' also retains semantic content.

Comment: @Lambie - I've never seen  the expression hyphenated like that.

Comment: @KateBunting But it isn't an expression. It's just someone expressing themselves like that.

Comment: _I don't know how many_ is an extended quantifier; _36_ or _a few_ or _many, many_ could substitute for it. The quantifier modifies (binds) the NP _crimes_, which is the object of _committed_.  The odd part is the fact that an independent sentence has been used as a quantifier; but quantifiers can have subordinate clauses and quite complex structure, e.g, _more than I would have expected_ is also a quantifier.

Comment: Yes: "I don't know how many crimes" is the direct object of "committed", but it's a noun phrase, not a clause, with "crimes" as head, and "I don't know" as modifier to "how"

Answer (score 4):

**Hyperextension of adjectives** is not two or even three. They are longer phrases and sometimes even a full sentence used as a prepositioned adjective.
AKA multiple hyphen compound adjective

Also dealt with here slightly differently: [answer 5 by Sven Yargs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84296/is-a-lengthy-combination-of-words-with-hyphens-like-the-worst-not-technically-i)

Here are two examples from an academic paper:   Hawking Hyphens
in Compound Modifiers

abstract:
Abstract

> **The first principle of legal writing is surely its clarity — visible actors (unless the action matters more), uncluttered syntax, and, of
> course, logical structure.** But the little things can matter to
> clarity, too — such as deliberate punctuation that signifies. In the
> language of law, in which compound nouns are rife, the reader can feel
> adrift as to where modifiers end and the noun begins. (Consider
> government-subsidized health flexible-spending arrangement without
> those hyphens.) Hyphens help. **Whether an author cares to hyphenate
> the noun is his call**; but hyphenating compound modifiers (also
> called phrasal adjectives, though they may include adverbs —
> more-abundant paperclips) follows a logic that is worth learning.
> **This essay describes that logic**. But its pitch is that legal writing, of all writing disciplines, should practice a deliberate,
> consistent use of such hyphens, rather than the more-relaxed practice
> readers see in less-formal writing (whose effects, of course, are
> usually also less consequential).
>
> There are limits, of course, to how far a compound stitched with
> hyphens can stretch. Brian Garner dubs such hyperextension “snakelike
> compounds,” and suggests “rework[ing] the sentence.”32 Exceptions are
> compounds crafted tongue in cheek, such as Fred Rodell’s typology of
> footnotes: “There is the explanatory or
> **if-you-didn’t-understand-what-I-said-in-the-text-this-may-help-you**
> type. And there is the probative or
> **if-you’re-from-Missouri-just-take-a-look-at-all-this** type.”33

[hyperextension of adjectives](https://scholarship.law.duke.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=6072&context=faculty_scholarship)

So, that gives us: He has committed I-don't-know-how-many crimes.
It is an example of a hyperextended adjective.

This type of hyperextension is found, yes, in comical texts but is also fairly common **in speech**. And therefore, in plays and scripts.

Examples I have just made up:

She is not a **for-better-or-for worse** woman.
They are not **but-I-don't-want-to-Mommy** kids.
We are definitely the **hold-your-nose-and-do-it** people in this kind of situation.

- And here is one I just found online in a formal text.

The second point is that the Protestant British (God bless them!1) undermined and obstructed the Catholic enterprise here; and, more tragically, the Anglo-American Catholicism that came with the Maryland colonizers was a weak, timid, **all-too-impressed-with-their-fellow-countrymen-who-were-heretics type of religion.** I shall save that second point, with its too-long hyphenated adjective, for another time. Now I would like to focus on the first point, our too-secret Catholic history.

[Catholicism](https://catholicism.org/ad-rem-no-99.html)

[All bolding is mine. I fully expect posters to post ones of their own under this answer. Perhaps they have ones that are more germane and funnier.]

Comment: you've got your upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly well accepted construction which, however does not fit into the traditional scheme of things in the grammar of English. What can be thought about it from the knowledgeable point of view of grammarians is given  a fundamental introduction in section 17.112 of the *Comprehensive Grammar of the English language* (Quirk et al, 1985). If one needs to refer  to the structure preceding such noun phrases as "crimes" in the query, one says that the structure can be considered either as  involving  *premodification by a sentence* or that the noun phrase is the object (of know) in an embedded nominal clause. The nature of this premodification is more or less adverbial; the premodification of nouns by regular adverbs is rather rare (an away game, the then chairman, in after years, …).

> (**CoGEL § 17.112**) **Premodification by sentence**
>
> What [can be] said of adverb phrases [as pertains to premodification of noun phrases] applies to premodification by a sentence :
>
> ♦ (?) I visited his *what do you call it* cottage [ *cf*: What do you call it when a
> cottage has walls made from overlapping pieces of'timber?
> Clapboard] [user LPH: *the interrogation point means that native speakers do not find this type of sentence fully acceptable.*]
>
> A few institutionalized examples retain a colloquial or slang flavour: *a whodunit story* is one about crime, and the nonstandard grammar or spelling are preserved as part of the ironic slang. *Do-it-yourself* as in *a do-it-yourself job* has become so often used as to pass out of the area of slang (and sometimes be reduced  to *DIY*).
>
> Somewhat more widely acceptable are noun phrases which can be interpreted either as having a sentence as premodifier or as being object (usually of *know*) in an embedded nominal clause:
>
> ♦   He asked *I don't know HÒW many* people. [user LPH: *"how" carries nuclear stress.*]  [1]
> ♦  He asked *I don't KNÒW how  many* people.  [1a]
>
> With either intonation, the meaning is 'He asked a relatively large number of people, though I don't know precisely how many'. The meaning is somewhat different if the sentence is reordered, enforcing a different grammatical structure:
>
> ♦ I don't know *how many people he asked*. ['I don't know the number of people he asked.']
>
> For the most part, however, sentence premodifiers have an air of the outrageous and improvised. Part of a political leader's election campaign was described by a journalist as
>
> *today's meet the people (if they can find you) tour*
>
> Far more remarkable is the following quotation from a literary comment in which the sentence premodification itself has highly irregular and sophisticated punctuation to convey highly irregular coordination devices:
>
> His other comments ignore. . . the obvious fallacies inherent in the
>        '*But the poem (play, novel) was meant to be  tedious/pretentious/pointless*' line of critical argument.

---

Note: There is matter for disagreement among grammarians in the assertion that such constructions as "away game" and "then chairman" show examples of premodification by adverbs. The SOED dictionary lists "away" and "then" as adjectives and gives the example "his then wife"; this approach appears to be preferable.

Comment: @Lambie This is not _my_ appreciation; I am quoting the grammar I have been using.  It takes into account the American version of the language, but perhaps not as well as the British since it has been written by British grammarians. It is possible also that you base your evaluation only on AmE. Moreover, you might consider nothing more than colloquial speech, whereas those grammarians might be thinking about a more formal type of English.

Comment: @Lambie Your source _is_ American (Duke University).; one of the authors is (or was, I think he might be dead too) from Sweden. Note that they do not mention compound adjectives though, and keep strictly to sentences. Nevertheless, their findings being now 35 years old, they are possibly not quite up to date; things will have changed in the domain of  premodification  by sentences.

Comment: You don't mean appreciation. You are using the French meaning of the word.

Comment: @Lambie You'd rather have "judgement", or more precisely, "assessment"? That is probably what you have in mind… however, they are synonyms or close synonyms (SOED).

Comment: When you say in French, une appréciation that is not appreciation in English. It is a faux ami here.  What I said in my answer has zero to do with AmE versus BrE. That is simply not relevant to understand this phrases-as-adjectives occurrences.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, mais dans ce contexte je ne crois pas être en train de penser en français, je crois bien penser en anglais; je suis bien dupé par les mots trompeurs, parfois, mais pas dans ce cas puisque je comprends "appreciation" comme signifiant "assessment". N'est-ce pas évident ?

Comment: @Lambie Anyway, "appréciation" does have the meaning "assessment" in French. See this reference (https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/appr%C3%A9ciation):  appréciation         nf     (=approbation)   appreciation   (=évaluation)   estimation, assessment

Comment: @Lambie Now, you've erased your commentary, and it is impossible to know what the matter is; you shouldn't do that if you intend to criticize and expect people to reply to you in a proper manner.

Comment: Find it hard to follow this thread with half of the comments vanished into thin air, but  I can vouch that in France  *appréciation* is what teachers write on/about students' works when assessing them. One can write *une bonne appréciation* or *une mauvaise appréciation* as appropriate, just as in Britain one can write a good or a bad assessment.

Answer (score 1):

These types of constructions are actually covered in CGEL (Ch. 11 *Content clauses and reported speech*, section 5.3.4, p. 984):

> A distinction needs to be drawn between the following constructions:
>
> i: He made some mistakes, though I don’t know how many.
>
> ii: He made I don’t know how many mistakes.
>
> In [i] *how many* is a reduced interrogative clause functioning as complement to know. This differs from the constructions we have been discussing only in the reduction of the interrogative clause; it is interpreted anaphorically as “how many mistakes he made”.
>
> In [ii], however, there is no ellipsis, and *how many mistakes* is not an interrogative clause. It means very much the same as "I don’t know how many mistakes he made", and its form seems in some way derivative from the latter. But clearly *made* is the verb of the
> matrix clause and the proposition that he made some mistakes is the main assertion, not backgrounded information; and there is an implicature that he made a large number of mistakes. Syntactically, *I don’t know how many mistakes* must be an object NP with
> *mistakes* as head; *I don’t know* functions as an irregular type of modifier to how.
>
> A variant of *I don’t know* is *God knows*. These modifiers occur with most of the interrogative words (though not *why*) – compare *They’re inviting God knows who to the reception.*

Comment: See also @BillJ's answer, which is almost identical to mine, except that he doesn't cite CGEL and phrases it in his own words.

Comment: CGEL does not cover this usage specifically where you have a full sentence or quasi-sentence used as an adjective. And this is not reported speech. I have provided numerous examples of this.

Comment: Could you explain to me why you think 'I don't know how many' is an adjective? What makes your analysis correct, and CGEL's wrong? (Apologies for the bluntness.) It may well be that CGEL's analysis is wrong, or at least not a definitive source on this matter.

Comment: It is not that CGEL's analysis is "wrong". It is a sentence premodifier. CGEL just don't analyze it **thoroughly** or give other typical examples.  As used in the OP's utterance, it is adjectival. If you  **move it** to the end of the sentence, it then **becomes something else** as in your i). The occurrence of three-hyphen phrases is well described "in the literature"; Longer phrases or sentences are not. However, it is very, very common in speech and also used in writing. See my answer and the link to Sven Yargs on a similar question.

Comment: Thanks for the bluntness. No beating around the bush. :)

Comment: @Lambie, after searching the Internet for some time,  I chanced upon several papers that deal with these types of constructions, which are called 'syntactic amalgams'. To my knowledge, these constructions were first analysed in detail by George Lakoff (a former professor of linguistics at UC Berkeley) in 1974; he defined 'syntactic amalgams' as 'sentences which have within them chunks of lexical material that do not correspond to anything in the logical structure of the sentence; rather they must be copied in other derivations under specifiable semantic and pragmatic conditions'. (Thread, 1/?)

Comment: Hey, Ben, That's GREAT. And  a good name for them. syntactic amalgams. Wouldn't want those in my teeth. My only disagreement is that I still contend they **function adjectivally** in the cases I describe and in the OP's sentence. You know, you'd think prof, editors would have stuff about this on the internet.

Comment: The syntax of such constructions is still a matter of considerable controversy. On the one hand, some sources (such as CGEL) contend that 'I don't know' in the sentence 'He committed I don't know how many crimes' is an irregular modifier of 'how many crimes', and that the syntactic function of 'I don't know how many crimes' is that of direct object; while others argue that 'I don't know many' is a complex determiner of 'crimes' (M. Guimaraes), with 'crimes' being the latter. I have yet to see any sources that argue that 'I don't know how many' has the role of an adjective, but... (2/3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129550/discussion-between-lambie-and-ben).

Comment: in view of the considerable uncertainty regarding the syntax of such constructions, one should not rule out the possibility.

Comment: I see no uncertainty in it at all.

Comment: In the example you give, there is most certainly no doubt whatsoever that 'damned-if-you do-damned-if-you-don't' is an adjective. But this example is not comparable with 'I don't know how many crimes' in the question. The main reason is that these syntactic amalgams (an awfully pretentious name, it must be said) can function as the complement of a preposition (as in 'The party will be at you know where', and 'John invited a lot of people to you can guess what kind of party), and not just a specific kind of preposition, but many of them. That is the most convincing reason I could find.

Comment: Oops. Was I meant to post this in the chat? Apologies

Comment: The problem here is that some people wrongly insist in using the misleading term 'adjectival' for everything that modifies a noun. "I don't know how many" may modify "mistakes", but it is not an adjective (phrase), not some kind of compound adjective.

Answer (score 0):

> *He has committed I don't know how many crimes.*

The meaning here is similar to "I don't know how many crimes he has committed", and in form seems in some way derivative from the latter.

But clearly "committed" is the verb of the matrix clause and the proposition that he committed some crimes is the main assertion, not backgrounded information; and there is a clear implicature that he committed a large number of crimes.

Syntactically, "I don't know how many crimes" must be an object NP (not a clause) with "crimes" as head. "I don't know" then functions as an irregular type of modifier to "how".